# Parse json from an external site with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to parse some json on an external site but I am having trouble. It must be with JavaScript or JQuery, as it is for a chrome extension. To get to the point:
I need to get the number from an external URL with the json {"_visitor_alertsUnread":"0"}  and set the number returned to a variable. How do I go about doing this?

I have tried several things such as JSON.parse but it isn't working:(

In short: How do I get the number from this json, which is on an external site, and set it to a variable?

Comment: Your question is *very* vague. You should try to pin it down to something more specific (preferrably with some code examples).

Comment: Okay, sorry, I'm just trying to figure out how to get the number from a json page on a external site.

Comment: 1. Get the data using ajax (helpful: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). 2. Parse JSON. (simple js object value dereferencing). Try implementing this and if it doesn't work update your question with the specific error and the code you tried. Good luck! :)

Comment: Edited question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: Are you running afoul the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which doesn't allow you to fetch much of anything from external sites?  If so, you might want to see if that external site offers [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or else set up a local proxy.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet I'm not because chrome extensions are allowed to bypass that with a permissions request. code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: Could you tell us __how__ it is not working? What happens when you use `JSON.parse()`? Does it throw an error? If so, can you post what that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get data from an external URL (in a different domain) in Javascript unless the site supports JSONP or Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. If it does, then use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the data and `JSON.parse()` to read it.

Script:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( 'GET', 'example.com/json', true );

xhr.onload = function () {
    var unread = window.JSON.parse( xhr.responseText )._visitor_alertsUnread;
};

xhr.onerror = function () {
    //process error
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks! It supports cross orgin:)

Answer (score 2):

Try this with http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON('your_url', function (jsonobj) {
    var unread;
    unread = jsonobj._visitor_alertsUnread;
});
```

Comment: +1 this way worked with me in my last project, but the file was in the same domain,